# Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed : Issues to link a function with a shiny app

Tags: r, twitter, shiny

I am meeting issues to display results of a function in a interractive shiny app. 
I created a function "Scraaping" that collects tweets from Twitter API and that is working when I run it alone, it takes in argument only a word between " ".
But when I want to get a text output from my app and insert it as an argument in my function which is running into server I am meeting bugs. It looks like it comes from the toString Function. 
Can you guys help on this ?

```
# Define UI for app 
 ui <- fluidPage(




  titlePanel('Twitter Scraping'),

        sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel("Work In Progress",
             h2("Input a research, get trends linked with it from Twitter"),
             actionButton("ActionButton", label = "Get Result"),
             dateRangeInput("Dates", label = "Dates de recherche",             start         = '2017-08-01', end = Sys.Date() ),
             textInput("Research" , label="Recherche" , value ='fintech'),
             selectInput("Localisation" , label ="Localisation", choices = c('Paris', 'Londres','Lyon','New York'))
               ),


  mainPanel (
          textOutput("Localisation"),
          textOutput("Dates") ,
          textOutput("Recherche1"),
          plotOutput("Plot")
          ) 
    # img(src = "my_image.png", height = 72, width = 72)    
         )
   )


   # server parameter
   server <- function(input, output) {



   # Appeler la fonction 

      output$Recherche2 <- renderText(input$Research)
    MotCle <- toString(output$Recherche2)  
   d <- Scrapping(MotCle) 
    Top10 <- head(d,10)  


   #Récupérer le graphe
        output$Localisation <- renderText({paste("Vous avez séléctionné la     localisation autour de" , input$Localisation)})
   output$Dates <- renderText({paste("Votre recherche porte du ", input$Dates[1],"au", input$Dates[2])})
    output$Recherche1 <- renderText({paste("La recherche porte sur les tweets contenant",input$Research)})


  output$Plot <- renderPlot( { output$Recherche2 <- renderText(input$Research)
                            MotCle <- toString(output$Recherche2) 
                            d <- Scrapping(MotCle) 
                            Top10 <- head(d,10)     

wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 10,
                                  max.words = 100 , random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
                                  colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2") ) })
```

}

And the Scrapping Function :

```
  Scrapping <- function(Recherche) {


  #Nombre de tweets souhaités
   NombreTweets <- 1000

  #Dates souhaitées
   Date_début = '2017-04-01'
   Date_fin = '2017-11-13'

   #Connexion à l'API
  Info_tweets <- searchTwitteR(Recherche, n=NombreTweets, since=Date_début,     until=Date_fin,
                         geocode = '48.878114,2.629798,100mi')


  # Extraction du texte // Construction du vecteur contenant le texte
  Tweets <- matrix(NA, nrow = NombreTweets)

for( i in 1:NombreTweets)
 Tweets[i] <- Info_tweets[[i]]$text
 #View(Tweets)

 #Textes = lapply(Info_tweets, function(t)t$getText())

 #Analyse des tweets 

   # Build a Corpus
  data.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(Tweets))
 data.corpus <- str_replace_all(data.corpus,"[[:punct:]]", " ") 
   # Remove all non-alphanumeric characters - just as backup to the special      chars 
  data.corpus <- str_replace_all(data.corpus,"[[:punct:]]", " ") 
  # Remove camelCase 
 data.corpus <- gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\L\\2", data.corpus, perl = TRUE)  
  # Lowercase 
   data.corpus <- tolower(data.corpus) 
  #' Remove everything that is not a number or letter (may want to keep more  
  #' stuff in your actual analyses).  
  data.corpus <- str_replace_all(data.corpus,"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", " ") 
 # Shrink down to just one white space 
  data.corpus <- str_replace_all(data.corpus,"[\\s]+", " ") 

 data.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data.corpus))

# remove punctuation & Numbers & double space
data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, removeNumbers)
 #data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, removePunctuation)
#data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, stripWhitespace)
data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, stemDocument)

 # Convert to lowercase
 data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))

 # Remove specific words 
 #data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, removeWords, c  (Recherche, "€", 'https'))

 #remove stop words, otherwise some of these words would appear as most used
 some_stopwordsEN <- c(stopwords('english'))
  some_stopwordsFR <- c(stopwords('french'))
 some_stopwordsESP <- c(stopwords('spanish'))
 data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, removeWords, some_stopwordsEN)
 data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, removeWords, some_stopwordsFR)
 data.corpus <- tm_map(data.corpus, removeWords, some_stopwordsESP)

  # Nuage de points 
 dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(data.corpus)
  m <- as.matrix(dtm)
  v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
  d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
  Top10 <- head(d, 10)

 set.seed(1234)
 wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 10,
      max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
      colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))


return(d)

 }
```

Comment: You cannot read an output item as you do here: `MotCle <- toString(output$Recherche2)`.This is forbidden. Why don't you do `toString(input$Research)` ?